# Is is possible to have fewer edges and vertices and still have a smooth character?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

Is is possible to have fewer edges and vertices and still have a smooth character? If possible then how? I know Darren Lille uses very few edges and vertices and still has smooth work.

Comment: yes, give your object a Subdivision Surface modifier, also right click and > Shade Smooth

Comment: If you use shade smooth, don't forget to go into the mesh properties (green upside-down triangle on the right) > Normals > Auto smooth or you might get shading artifacts. And subdivision surface modifier will actually add geometry even if it is dynamically so keep that in mind

Comment: Perhaps related: [Approximation of smooth surfaces with polygonal meshes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/165593/)